# How to read a query result

Tags: cakephp

I have a query in CakePHP as following :

```
lnguserID = 10;
$result = $this->Mymodel->find('all', array(
              'fields' => array('Mymodel.intPhoneID'),
              'conditions' => array('Mymodel.intUserid'=> $lnguserID)
            ));
```

When I debug the result like this: `echo debug($result);`

I get :

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Mymodel' => array(
            'intPhoneID' => (int) 3975
        )
    )
)
```

How can I access directly to this `id` : `3975` from the resulted array? Something like :

```
result['Mymodel']['intPhoneID'];
```

I want to use it in an other query.

Comment: hhhhh, hi, Working thanks.

Answer (score 0):

```
echo $result[0]['Mymodel']['intPhoneID'];
```

Also - you don't need to `echo` a debug.  It's just:

```
debug($result[0]['Mymodel']['intPhoneID']);
```

I assume this is in the Controller - if so, you can then access it in the View by "'set'ing" it:

```
// Controller
$this->set('result', $result);

// View
debug($result);
```

Answer (score 0):

if this is your object:

```
array(
    (int) 0 => array(
        'Mymodel' => array(
            'intPhoneID' => (int) 3975
        )
    )
)
```

you need to access the array by 0 -> Mymodel -> intPhoneID , so use:

```
result[0]['Mymodel']['intPhoneID'];
```